# Proving that $BPP^{BPP}=BPP$

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, probabilistic-algorithms, oracle-machines

I'm trying to prove that $BPP^{BPP}=BPP$.

$BPP\subseteq BPP^{BPP}$ is obvious. I'm struggling with $BPP^{BPP}\subseteq BPP$..

Can anyone help?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: $\mathsf{BPP}^\mathsf{BPP}$ is the class of problems poly-time Turing-reducible (i.e., Cook-reducible) to $\mathsf{BPP}$. Hence: Try answering the oracle queries by solving them directly and using error reduction (i.e., a Chernov bound) as needed.